# Is there a mapping file for R8-minimized android resource files?

Tags: proguard, android-r8

In the case of a minimized but not obfuscated APK, R8 still scrambles the resource file names in the R8 build step. The APK, when unzipped, have resource file names like `0c9.png`, `0F.xml` and `1g.xml`, while the original names were `button_blue.xml`, `button_red.xml` etc.

Is there any way to reverse-map these back to identifiable resource file names?

I looked through the build output to see if there were mapping files generated for this kind of renaming but I couldn't find anything. `mapping.txt` only applies to Kotlin/Java code. `resources.txt` seems to be about usage, not renmaing.

Optionally, is there a way to minimize resources *without* renaming the files?

My build gradle for the release build

```
release {
    minifyEnabled true
    shrinkResources true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), '../proguard-rules.pro'
    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
}
```

My proguard file `../proguard-rules.pro` contains this line

```
-dontobfuscate
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://issuetracker.google.com/316831822#comment2:

This is not R8, and it is not resource shrinker either, this is renamed by the resource name shortener in AAPT2 (that agp invokes by default)

If you want to know what the original name of say `res/Z.png` is you can do:

```
aapt2 dump resources my.apk | grep "res/Z.png"
```